# Rate of convergence of a sum of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_k=1/k$ and $b_k$ is a positive sequence with  $ b_k \to 0$. Is there any result that establishes the rate of decay of $b_k$, if $$ \sum_k a_kb_k < \infty $$

or when can in general $\sum_k a_k b_k $  be finite if $b_k \to 0$ and is positive for all $k$, and $a_k=1/k$

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no result establishing the rate of decay exactly. This follows from a close analysis of the $p$-series test: that is, $\sum n^{-p}$ converges for $p>1$, but the rate of convergence need not be so fast. The sum $\sum n^{-1}(\log n)^{-p}$ also converges for $p>1$ and its rate of convergence is strictly slower than $\sum n^{-p}$.

Applying a similar process, we have $\sum (n\log n)^{-1}(\log\log n)^{-p}$ converges for $p>1$, so on and so forth. In your notation, this means $b_n=(\log n)^{-1}(\log\log n)^{-p}$, or to go one step further, $b_n=(\log n\log\log n)^{-1}(\log\log\log n)^{-p}$.

In all of these cases, it *is* true that $b_n\ll\frac{1}{\log n}$, so you at least have a minimum rate of decay. This isn't true in general; see the comments for an example where you can prescribe the rate of decay as slowly as you see fit.

**Note:** The requirement of positivity for $b_n$ can be loosened to positive for all sufficiently large $n$ since we can just otherwise take $b_n=1$ for the first $N$ terms and then define it using the logarithms for $n\geq N+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: @user143234: you are welcome.

Comment: What about say $$b_k = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log k}} &\text{ if } k \text{ is a power of } 2\\ \frac{1}{k^2} &\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$? It does *not* satisfy $b_k \ll \frac{1}{\log k}$...

Comment: @ClementC.: Of course. While different from the example I had thought of, your example fits in just fine (that is, I had thought of an example that doesn't satisfy the decay property listed; it doesn't change that the $b_n$ I've defined do satisfy it, though). It seemed like the OP simply wanted to know that there was no definitive, exact rate of decay (for which there isn't).

Comment: @Clayton: my example is basically to say your sentence "*but you can provide some estimate on how quickly it decays*" is wrong. You cannot... you can have a subsequence of $(b_k)_k$ going to zero arbitrarily slowly.

Comment: Simply for the record, I had thought of: $$b_n=\begin{cases}1 &:n=k^2\\ n^{-2} &:\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ In this instance, we don't even have $b_n\to0$, but via obvious modifications, you can make it decay to $0$ as slowly as desired.

Comment: @ClementC.: Ah, correct. When I thought of my example, I didn't look back and read through the entire post. You're correct. I've edited it out and provided commentary toward my example above.